# Update SQL Server from GridView with a Checkbox

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

There is a GridView with a Checkbox field on the page. And there is a button on the same page. There is a field which is related to the checkbox in the sql. Is there any simple way to update the sql? Not row by row.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet to return the values of all selected checkboxes as a comma-separated string:

```
string values = string.Empty;
foreach (ListItem item in checkboxList.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected)
    values += item.Value + ",";
}
```

You can use this value in SQL as follows:

```
string sql = String.Format("UPDATE table SET selected = 1 WHERE ID IN ({0})", values );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing each row individually I'm afraid there's not other way that updating row by row or you can have a batch update for each group of values for example:

```
Update MyTable Set checkbox=1 WHERE Id IN(list of ids);

Update MyTable Set checkbox=0 WHERE Id IN(list of ids);
```

If you'd like to update the same value for all the rows that are shown you can do this:

```
Update MyTable set checkbox=value WHERE your whare cluase of showing fields
```